# How to render a QOpenGLFramebufferObject to QQuickItem

Tags: qt, opengl-es, qquickitem, qopenglfunctions

I am using Qt 5.6 & above. I have a `QQuickItem` sub-class which is placed in my `main.qml`

```
class MyQQuickItem : public QQuickItem {

}
```

In my `main.cpp` I register `MyQQuickItem` using `qmlRegisterUncreatableType`. It displays fine on the app main UI screen.

Now, I have a valid texture which is `QOpenGLFramebufferObject`. I just want to display this `QOpenGLFramebufferObject` on the UI of `MyQQuickItem`.

**Probably I should call update on `MyQQuickItem` somehow providing this texture to it ? How can do this?**

Comment: By implementing `updatePaintNode` and returning some scenegraph nodes that draw your texture. In case, did you consider to use QQuickFramebufferObject directly instead?

Comment: @peppe How can I use `QOpenGLFramebufferObject` directly ? any examples you can point me to ?

Comment: is there a way to trigger `updatePaintNode` manually ?